Azure Blob Storage SAS URL generation issue with managed identity
I am encountering an issue when generating a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL for a file in Azure Blob Storage using managed identity. The generated SAS URL contains a '+' sign in the signature field, which causes the error "Signature fields not well formed" when trying to use the URL for access.
public string GenerateSaS(string account,
                          string containerName,
                          string fileName,
                          int expiryTimeInMins)
{
    try
    {
        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("<My CLient Id>") });
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/"), tokenCredential);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Check if the container exists
        if (!containerClient.Exists())
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Create a BlobSasBuilder instance
        var sharedPolicy = new BlobSasBuilder
        {
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryTimeInMins),
            ContentDisposition = $"attachment;filename={fileName}",
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            BlobName = fileName,
            Resource = "b", // Blob-level access
            Protocol = SasProtocol.Https // Use HTTPS only
        };
        sharedPolicy.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write | BlobSasPermissions.Create);

        // Generate SAS token and create BlobUriBuilder
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        var blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
        {
            Sas = sharedPolicy.ToSasQueryParameters(blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-2), DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2)), blobServiceClient.AccountName)
        };

        // Convert BlobUriBuilder to URL string
        var url = blobUriBuilder.ToUri().ToString();

        return url;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
        throw ex;
    }
}

Signature sample in the url => sig=7SAJlSwRz8RNMQkEV4Y+hfIMEfVIRFapY49U/vqf4cI=
I tried diffrent ways to generate the url but no luck.
I am expecting a working solution for this issue


Azure Blob Storage SAS URL generation issue with managed identity

You can use the code below to generate the Azure Blob Storage SAS URL using .Net code.
Code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;

namespace SAStoken
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var account = "venkat123";
            var containerName = "test";
            var fileName = "imp.png";
            var Credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("<My CLient Id>") });
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/"), Credential);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            var userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));

            var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
                BlobName = blobClient.Name,
                Resource = "b", // b for blob, c for container
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
            };
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write | BlobSasPermissions.Create);

            BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
            {
                // Specify the user delegation key.
                Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey, blobServiceClient.AccountName)
            };

            Console.WriteLine("BlobSAS URI: {0}", blobUriBuilder);
        }

    }
}

Output:
BlobSAS URI: https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/imp.png?skoid=6xxxxxx&sktid=72fxxxxxx-41af-91ab-2d7xxb47&skt=2024-04-29T07%3A16%3A33Z&ske=2024-04-30T07%3A16%3A33Z&sks=b&skv=2023-11-03&sv=2023-11-03&spr=https&st=2024-04-29T07%3A16%3A37Z&se=2024-04-29T11%3A16%3A37Z&sr=b&sp=rcw&sig=reHWCZ0lNDyBGxxxxxfH4Z3I7E%3D


Browser:


Can you please share some light on what is the difference you made? I see removing content-deposition, and getting the Delegation Key before?

Is the above approach worked for you?

Removed ContentDisposition to ignore download instead to view the picture.

Yes it worked for me. But i dont understand why removing ContentDisposition worked? Also what different in this case that i did not get the plus sign?

I used with ContentDisposition in my code like https://i.imgur.com/Y5PFDo2.png When I copied paste the Url in the browser it will get download https://i.imgur.com/r6df6W3.png

Any idea why it worked?

In the commented code I provided, the ContentDisposition property is included, but it is URL-encoded using the Uri.EscapeDataString method. This method replaces the '+' sign with '%2B', which is a valid character in a URL. Therefore, the SAS token is generated without any issues.

I did not get it, you have removed ContentDisposition. At what step it removed the + sign?
